# Change MariaDB "ADMIN_OPTION" of a ROLE after deleting the user who created it

Tags: mariadb, users, role, mariadb-10.6

I have a problem in the prod :

I have a user named dba who has all privileges with grant option, i used it to create a role named test, i granted some rights to the role test and granted the role test to the user 'name.name'@'10.25%'.

the problem is that i deleted the user dba, so now my role lost the user who had his ADMIN OPTION.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT count(*),User,Role,Admin_option FROM mysql.roles_mapping group by role DESC;
+----------+----------------------+-------------+--------------+
| count(*) | User                 | Role        | Admin_option |
+----------+----------------------+-------------+--------------+
|        1 | name.name            | test        | N            |       
+----------+----------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

now i recreated the user dba,

Is there a way to give back the ADMIN OPTION to dba using another super user like root ?

what are the possible solutions to back to the normal status ?

```
mariadb info : 
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.6.8-MariaDB-1:10.6.8+maria~stretch-log mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:       10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as the `dba` user (assuming it has all privileges with grant option again) you can simply drop the role and re-create it, then grant it to the `name.name` user again:

```
DROP ROLE test;
CREATE ROLE test;
GRANT test to 'name.name'@'10.25%';
```

This should give you the same contents in `mysql.roles_mapping` as you had before.